# How do I change the name of the file field in simple_form when a file exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Profile` model that:

```
  has_many :transcripts, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :transcripts, allow_destroy: true
```

So on my `app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb`, I have the following:

```
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :transcripts do |transcript| %>
        <%= render 'transcript_fields', f: transcript %>
      <% end %>
```

And the `app/views/profiles/_transcript_fields.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<%= f.file_field :attachment, class: 'col-lg-4 form-control' %>
```

So what I want to do is on the `_transcript_fields` partial, when the `profile` has existing `transcripts`, I want it to display a file field that has the name of the file attached -- that way if they want to change that file that was attached, they can just click upload on that same `file_field` and it will update that Transcript record.

I have the actual update operation working now, but what happens is, it just shows the fields like this:

[image]

Where the top `file_field` is the existing file, and the bottom one reflects a new field that can be added.

Comment: As one of the answers said, it can't be done. Its a security issue. You will have to find another way to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: If you were to use something like carrierwave to handle the uploads it will allow you to do some of this as it can persist the filename, etc. This or perhaps refile. Unfortunately as you've discovered you don't want your browser to be able to mutate files on the file system beyond a certain point so this is a security issue you're running up against. Having said that... once you have the uploaded file binary data in the controller method. You could name it whatever you want at that point before you persist it. So you can do the manipulation on the Rails' side once the data is persisted.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

The only way to set the value of a file input is when the user selects a file from his system.If you will do it forcefully it will apper like this in HTML.

```
<form name="foo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" value="c:/rails.png">
</form>
```

This is done for security reasons. Otherwise you would be able to create a Javascript that automatically uploads a specific file from the clients computer, but if you want to have some edit functionality of an uploaded file field, what you probably want to do is:

1. Show the current value of this field by just printing the filename or URL, a clickable link to download it, or if it's an image: just show it, possibly as thumbnail.
2. The file_field to upload a new file.
3. A checkbox that, when checked, deletes the currently uploaded file. note that there's no way to upload an 'empty' file, so you need something like this to clear out the field's value.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Kinda....the issue though is that I have seen file fields that have the name of the attached file...so I am wondering how they have done it.

Answer (score 2):

In the `_transcript_fields` partial you can check if the current `transcript` object is already persisted or not. Based on that, it's possible to render something different.

Something like:

```
# app/views/profiles/_transcript_fields.html.erb
<% if f.object.persisted? %>
  <%= f.object.name %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.file_field :attachment, class: 'col-lg-4 form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So this partly gets me there. I guess the real question is, how do I fill in the name of the `file_field` with the name of the file, when `f.object.persisted?`

Comment: I don't think you want to use a `file_field` for a file that has already been uploaded. Just showing the filename in a span/div should be enough.